# Can ubiquity install ubuntu 19.04 and not ubuntu core 16?

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

I installed ubiquity using apt on a running Disco dingo, but when installing a new version of ubuntu using ubiquity, it installs ubuntu core 16 instead, which does not come with apt and uses snap. Is there anyway to get ubiquity to install ubuntu 19 instead?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu Core 19 (nor any Ubuntu 19).  Ubuntu *disco dingo* is Ubuntu 19.04, with Ubuntu Core being release every second year (the year of the LTS release, so Ubuntu Core 18 for 2018, Ubuntu Core 16 for 2016)

Comment: Ok. ubiquity installs ubuntu core 16 for some reason. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Since i booted into a running system and not into a livecd, i assume the default for ubiquity is to use ubuntu core 16, which is the smallest install for ubuntu. But, i'd like for it to use either the current running system or another version like disco dingo. Is that possible?